# ASP.NET MVC DropDownListFor doesn't set selected data to true in List

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a view which has a model that is an IEnumerable. I use DropDownListFor Html helper in a foreach loop to output dropdown lists. But it doesn't set the selected item to true. Code as below:

```
@model IEnumerable<Example>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.FilePath, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ConfigFiles, string.Empty, null)
}
```

The above code output a Html select element. But none of the options are selected even though the item.FilePath has the same value as one of the options.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unfortunate limitation of using `DropDownListFor()` in a loop, and you need to generate a new `SelectList` in each iteration. However, your use of a `foreach` loop to generate the form controls will not work. Its creating duplicate `name` attributes which have no relationship to your model therefore will not bind, and its also generating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html.

Change your model to `IList<T>` and use a `for` loop and generate a new `SelectList` in each iteration using the constructor that sets the `selectedValue`

```
@model IList<Example>
....
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].FilePath, new SelectList(ViewBag.ConfigFiles, "Value", "Text", Model[i].FilePath), string.Empty, null)
}
```

Note that this now generate `name` attributes which binds to your model

```
<select name="[0].FilePath">....<select>
<select name="[1].FilePath">....<select>
.... etc
```

Note that its not necessary to create `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in the controller. Your could instead assign a collection of your objects to `ViewBag`

```
ViewBag.ConfigFiles = db.ConfigFiles;
```

and in the view

```
new SelectList(ViewBag.ConfigFiles, "ID", "Name") // adjust 2nd and 3rd parameters to suit your property names
```